# MODX 2.7.0 installation fails: ERROR in xPDOConnection

Tags: modx-revolution

Trying to install MODX revolution 2.7.0, I keep getting this error at an early stage of installation while the system is testing connection to the database server:

```
(ERROR in xPDOConnection::connect @ [...]/core/xpdo/xpdo.class.php : 3119) SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/tmp/mysql.sock' (2)
```

The server is running PHP 5.6 (I also tried PHP 7.x) and MySQL 5.6.41 with a new database (UTF8_general_ci collation) while all MODX installation files are stored in a newly created folder with at least CHMOD 775 access rights for debugging purposes. I also checked the connection details for the database server several times and even removed the password from the database to check if there was any typo involved.

I am running out of ideas. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. SimpleXML PHP module was not activated and I was using the wrong MySQL Server adress.